# Como criar animação de imagem girando, com velocidade decrescente, até parar

Tags: android, animação, android-xml

Eu tenho esta animacao abaixo em em que uma ImagemView gira sobre seu eixo durante 4 segundos. Gira uniforme com a mesma velocidade os 4 segundos.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="4000"
        android:startOffset="0"/>
</set>
```

Como faço uma animação que comece girando normal mas vá diminuindo até parar, nos mesmos 4 segundos. Exemplo: Um pneu de carro. Ta girando, mas ao frenar o carro, este pneu vai diminuindo a velocidade até parar totalmente?

Comment: ramaral, deu certo! E eu não ia descobrir nem tão cedo. Eu comecei de umas 20 hs a tentar resolver isso, deu 4 da manha e eu nao consegui. É porque eu esta indo por outros caminhos... Eu usei Handler, usei for(...) variando o setStartOffset, etc. Muito obrigado... Abraços...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A animação é conseguida fazendo variar uma característica, neste caso a rotação.

A forma como essa característica varia ao longo do tempo é determinada pelo [Interpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator) usado.

Assim, querendo que haja uma desaceleração, em vez de um LinearInterpolator, use um [DecelerateInterpolator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/DecelerateInterpolator.html)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
        <rotate
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:toDegrees="360"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:duration="4000"
            android:startOffset="0"/>
    </set>
```

Comment: ramaral, agora surgiu um problema, que é a velocidade. Se usar 1 segundo ele gira bem rapido ate parar. Se usar 10 segundos ele gira bem devagar ate parar, ou seja, a animacao usa um numero fixo de giros. Como aumentar esta quantidade de giros para ao usar 10 segundos comece com a mesma velocidade do uso com 1 segundo?

Comment: O número de rotações é determinado pelo valor atribuído a `android:toDegrees`. Use um múltiplo de 360: 1x360 uma volta, 2x360 duas voltas, ...... .

Comment: Ramaral, agora foi que vi que nao tinha comentado a sua resposta ainda (desde abril). Deu certo. Obg...

Comment: Basta, como fez; aceitar a resposta para saber que foi útil.:)

Comment: Vou fazer isso sempre agora...